# (Help Needed) Time between two dates w/o Dateti

Tags: python, date, datetime, module, days

I have to calculate the time between two dates in days in Python,  but without the `datetime` module.

I managed to parse a date without `datetime`:

```
def date(error):
    global sdate
    if error:
        print(sdate," isn't a valable date ! ")
    sdate = input('Date : ')
    try:
        ldate = sdate.split('.')
        ldate = [ int(x) for x in ldate]
        day,month,year = ldate
    except ValueError:
        date(True)
    if year%4==0 and year%100!=0 or year%400==0:
        bis = True
    else:
        bis = False
    if month not in range(1,13):
        date(True)
    if month not in(1,3,5,7,8,10,12):
        mmax = 31
    elif month in(4,6,9,11):
        mmax = 30
    elif month == 2 and bis == True:
        mmax = 29
    elif month == 2 and bis == False:
        mmax = 28
    if day not in range(1,mmax+1):
        date(True)
date(None)
print(ldate)
```

But didn't figure out how to get time between dates.

What's the easiest way?

Thanks,
Blaxou

PS: It's not a Homework at all, I need it for a personal project where I use any of too easy-life-making modules ;)

Comment: If you avoid `datetime`, it will be neither easy nor Pythonic.

Comment: Try coming up with some sample code. What have you tried up to this point?

Comment: I'll edit the question soon

Comment: Please format your code and post it. There is no proper indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do much more than that to check the difference between two dates.

I will give you pseudo code to do this, write your own program.

```
• get the dates
• validate the dates 
    -> (ex. It should be false for feb 29 2007)
• calculate total number of days of that particular year for both dates 
    -> (ex 1 jan 2015 = 01 and 28 feb 2016 = 59)
• calculate the year difference
• calculate number of leap years between two days (excluding both end)
    -> (2004 and 2008 leap year is 0)
• calculate the difference by
  diff(number of days) + (year difference * 365) + number of leap years
```

Comment: Its too long to write a program.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write a program, was just a precision ;)

Comment: Then, use the pseudo code I've given. It should work well.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm not sure to understand the "excluding both end"

Comment: `(2004 and 2008 leap year is 0)` You shold not consider 2004 or 2008. whereas for 2004 and 2009, leap year is 1

Comment: Yeah I didn't understand this part, why is it 0, 2004 is a leap year isn't it?

Comment: You will be adding them in the month calculations. Also _Both end_ means  starting point & ending point. Here 2004 and 2008 are starting and ending.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll probably post my final program.

Comment: Hey, I came up with something but couldn't figure out how to count leap years between two years m without counting them one at a time. Is there an easier method?

Comment: `sum([ 1 for year in range(start_year+1,end_year) if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or  year%400==0])`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it this afternoon !